# codeigniter, datamapper and ion_auth error is leaving me confused

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-datamapper

when i call this-

```
$o = new Order();
```

codeigniter gives me this error-

```
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined property: order::$ion_auth_model

Filename: libraries/Loader.php

Line Number: 1035


Fatal error: Call to a member function _assign_libraries() on a non-object in C:\xampplite\htdocs\portraits\system\libraries\Loader.php on line 1035
```

At the minute the order model isnt doing anything other than whats in the _template from datamapper 1.8

here is the db schema for the order table

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `orders` (
  `order_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `image_path` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `status` enum('new','progress','completed','sent') NOT NULL,
  `placed` date NOT NULL,
  `updated_date` date NOT NULL,
  `will_send` int(1) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`order_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

This is what i was trying to do..

```
$o->user_id = $user->id;
            $o->status = 'new';
            $o->placed = unix_to_human(time(), TRUE, 'eu');;
            $o->will_send = 1;
```

any guidance on why CI is trying to load the auth model to the user class? or what am i missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Where is the Order class?
- How do you include it to your code?
- Does Order class standalone? or integrated to CodeIgniter?
- Did you check/change your Ion_Auth config?
- Did you ever tried to change the codes in Ion_Auth?
- Did you try to call a variable from ion_auth that is not exists? (Eg: `$this->ion_auth->order;` or `$this->ion_auth_model->order;` )
- Did you call CI superclass in Order class? If you trying to do access CodeIgniter's classes and functions, you have to get the CI instance inside Order class. Eg;

  ```
  Class Order
  {
      public function __construct()
      {
          //Calling CI superclass to use libraries, models, helpers, views etc...
          $this->ci =& get_instance();

          //using CI's libraries:
          if ($this->ci->ion_auth->logged_in())
          {
              //Do stuff here...
          }
      }
  }
  ```